# How to modify a menu to show sub-menus

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, e-commerce, categories

I have a custom php menu made by another person, it basically displays the categories as a menu. However, we need it to display subcategories as well. I tried adding a hierarchical parameter but it didn't work. Hoping for some assistance!

Here is the code:

```
<ul>
<?php
/* Get all the categories for wp e-commerce products */
$wpec_product_categories = get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', 'hide_empty=0&parent=0&exclude=298');
$myarray = array();
foreach($wpec_product_categories as $wpec_categories){
    $myarray[$wpec_categories->term_id]['name'] = $wpec_categories->name;
    $myarray[$wpec_categories->term_id]['slug'] = $wpec_categories->slug;
    $myarray[$wpec_categories->term_id]['term_id'] = $wpec_categories->term_id;
}
foreach($myarray as $wpec_categories1){
    $wpec_term_name = $wpec_categories1['name'];
    $wpec_term_slug = $wpec_categories1['slug'];
    $wpec_term_id = $wpec_categories1['term_id'];
    echo '<li> <a href="'.get_page_link(19).''.$wpec_term_slug.'" >'. $wpec_term_name.'</a></li>';
}
?></ul>
```

Comment: In the code above what would you call a hierarchical parameter?

Comment: I took it out because I figured it was wrong, or it would have worked...